# are there pre-processor directives in fortran like those in C?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, preprocessor-directive

I am wondering if there are pre-processor directives in fortran that is similar to C's `#ifdef ... #endif`?

Comment: Yes, but not standard. Still pretty usable though. In gfortran they preprocessor runs only in the traditional mode, the features are limited incomparison to C99 or C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are. In fact, they typically are the same. For `gfortran` you can enable the preprocessor by using the option `-cpp`, for `ifort` you can use `-fpp`.

Also, there is a convention, that a capital `F` in `*.F` and `*.F90` enables the pre-processor, while `*.f` and `*.f90` does not.

Comment: ...though technically the use of the C preprocessor isn't "in Fortran".

Comment: Another option is to call the c pre-processor directly before compiling your Fortran code.  E.g. `cpp -P -traditional -DWHATEVER code.F90 > code.f90 ; gfortran -c code.f90`

Comment: The convention for .F and .F90 does not apply to Windows.

Comment: @SteveLionel That makes sense somehow ;-) Thanks! [I don't use Windows...]

Comment: Just to close on my comment - Windows is case-preserving but not case-sensitive on file names, so .f and .F are treated the same.